# socket io server connection fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, next.js, socket.io

I am trying to create a basic game using next.js and node.js. When I run it I get multiple "connected" logs and when I check adapters  -using io.sockets.adapter.rooms- I get even though there is just one client (One tab on chrome) connected:

io.sockets.adapter.rooms log:

```
 Map(4) {
  'tiTjbdGFj3EGgbwRAAAB' => Set(1) { 'tiTjbdGFj3EGgbwRAAAB' },
  'DsCKvImAuh8H6Vr3AAAD' => Set(1) { 'DsCKvImAuh8H6Vr3AAAD' },
  'FtJispkyF08rhHBDAAAF' => Set(1) { 'FtJispkyF08rhHBDAAAF' },
  'PFO72' => Set(1) { 'FtJispkyF08rhHBDAAAF' }
}
```

app.js(server backend)

```
const app = require('express')();
const server =  require('http').createServer(app);
const fs = require('fs');
const dirImage = './public/images';
const path = require( 'path' );

const io = require('socket.io')(server, {
    cors: {
        origin: "http://localhost:3000",
        methods: ["GET", "POST"],

    }
});
server.listen(8000);
```

frontend react context socket connection:

```
import {createContext} from 'react';
import io from "socket.io-client";



    export const socket = io("http://localhost:8000", {transports : ['websocket']});


    export const SocketContext = createContext(socket);
```

Also creating socket variable in every page using useContext hook:

```
    const socket = useContext(SocketContext);
```

When I run the server I still get 5 connections from one client

```
Connected! 
 Connected! 
 Connected! 
 Connected! 
 Connected!
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 2):

from your frontend app, you are using context api to connect socket but not using useEffect Hooks, So your connection line is running multiple time as how many time your app is re-rendering. I suggest to use useEffect hook with empty dependency array to run the connection only in first render.

I am attaching a sample code for you:

```
  import io from "socket.io-client";

  useEffect(() => {
      socket = io.connect("http://localhost:8000");

      return () => {
        socket.disconnect();
      };
  
  }, []);
```

This will connect your socket connection first time and it will disconnect when the component ejects.

Comment: Where should I use useEffect hook? While I using create context in its file or should I add the hook to all pages?

Comment: No, in the context you have to declare UseEffect hook, where you are connecting the socket. Just to run the connection only once!

Answer (score 2):

Should it be like this?

context file:

```
const SocketContext = createContext();


const SocketContextProvider = ({children}) =>{
     const [socket,setSocket] = useState(null);
    useEffect(()=>{
          setSocket(io.connect("http://localhost:8000"));

    },[]);
     return (
         // the Provider gives access to the context to its children
         <SocketContext.Provider value={socket}>
              {children}
         </SocketContext.Provider>
     );

}
export {SocketContext,SocketContextProvider}
```

Comment: yes that will work I hope!

Answer (score 0):

The better approach is to autoConnect option to false and manually connect client by using:
step 1:
//it will prevent the client from autoconnecting
const socket = io({autoconnect: false});
step 2:
//it will connect the client
socket.connect()